# Selenium Webdriver with Python - Not able to give input in a web application using Selenium Web driver

Tags: python, selenium

[image]I've been trying to make a Python script to login into a certain website, navigate through the menu, fill out a form and save the file it generates to a folder.
But at this point I can't fill out the form, probably because it is not in the website HTML. It is more like a new window.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://directa.natal.rn.gov.br/")
#Logando
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"frame\[name='mainsystem'\]\[src^='main'\]")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.input\[name='usuario'\]"))).send_keys("11844691000126")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.input\[name='senha'\]").send_keys("Link2007")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn#acessar").click()
#Nota natalense
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"frame\[name='mainsystem'\]\[src^='main'\]")))
driver.find_element_by_id('limenu9').click()
#operações
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.submenu\[value='formsmenu14'").click()
#download de NF-e
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#formsmenu14 > li:nth-child(4)').click()
#Selecionar empresa
```

Comment: Post your html might be that window is on new frame you need to switch frame. if that is frame elements.

Comment: Give input to which field?

Comment: @DebanjanB To the date field for example

Comment: @VictorMedeiros You have got an accepted answer now. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help, I have just provided the way to reach to the frame and enter a single value on that form, you can add rest:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://directa.natal.rn.gov.br/")
#Logando
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name("mainsystem"))
driver.find_element_by_id('usuario').send_keys('11844691000126')
driver.find_element_by_id("senha").send_keys("Link2007")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn#acessar").click()
#Nota natalense
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"mainsystem")))
driver.find_element_by_id('limenu9').click()
time.sleep(1)
#operações
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#limenu9 > div > a:nth-child(3) > span:nth-child(1)")))
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#limenu9 > div > a:nth-child(3) > span:nth-child(1)')
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
#download de NF-e
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="formsmenu14"]/li[4]/a/span').click()

time.sleep(1)
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="WFRInput668298"]').send_keys('1')
```